# How to pass an argument in django templatetag or call form valid like in the views?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

Hi Guys I want to add CreateView to be accessible all my web pages, so I opted for template tags, which bring out the form quite nicely but it can't save. I believe because of the user field which I want to be automatically added before saving the form. in Views.py is quite simple.

```
class BusinessCreate(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Business
    form_class = BusinessAddForm
    template_name = 'business/form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user # this is what i want to add in templatetags
        messages.success(self.request, 'successfully created your biashara')

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

this is my form.py

```
class BusinessAddForm(ModelForm):
    logo = forms.ImageField(label='', required=False, widget=forms.FileInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'your logo'}))
    description = forms.Field(label='', widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'placeholder': 'Describe your biashara'}))
    name = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your biashara name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', required=True, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Business
        fields = (
            'name', 'logo', 'email', 'description')
```

Now I have a template tag
templatetags/business.py

```
from django.template import Library

from business.forms import BusinessAddForm

register = Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('includes/business_form.html', takes_context=True)
def get_business_form():
    form = BusinessAddForm()
    return {
        'form': form,
    }
```

which renders the form quite well but doesn't save. No errors though.
so where can I add the current logged in user to user Field?

my models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='added_by', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    logo = models.ImageField(upload_to="business/logos", blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(help_text="This is required")
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Thanks guys in advance

Comment: It simply can not save... Since it needs to make a HTTP request to a view to handle the submitted form. You thus should define a view to which the form will submit (with `<form method="post" action="...some-url-that-processes-the-view...">`), and thus a view that then handles it accordingly.

Comment: Let me do this and I'll tell you the results.